# How to progress my Five Dice game

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, dice

I am learning to program, in particular starting with C# where I have been experimenting with dice games to become more familiar and to improve myself. I am now trying to create a basic game in windows forms, where two players roll 5 dice and keep record of their score.

Rules:

- Begin with 5 dice
- If a 1 or 4 appears, player scores no points and those dice are removed. Otherwise add all the dice to total
- Continue with remaining dice until there a no dice left over

So far I have an Image array which stores all my dice images in my resources and a button which will roll the dice. What I need help with specifically is being able to remove the penalized dice (setting that particular one back to blank) and allowing the player to continue rolling their remaining dice until none are left.

At the moment I am unsure as to where I can further this and maybe I am biting off more than I can chew. I am loving coding and any help would be much appreciated.

Here's an image of the interface:

[image]

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Image[] diceImages;
    int[] dice;
    int[] diceResults;
    Random random;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        diceImages = new Image[7];
        diceImages[0] = Properties.Resources.blank;
        diceImages[1] = Properties.Resources.one;
        diceImages[2] = Properties.Resources.two;
        diceImages[3] = Properties.Resources.three;
        diceImages[4] = Properties.Resources.four;
        diceImages[5] = Properties.Resources.five;
        diceImages[6] = Properties.Resources.six;

        dice = new int[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        random = new Random();

        diceResults = new int[6] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    }

    private void btn_rollDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RollDice();

        GetResults();

        ResetResults();
    }

    private void RollDice()
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)
        {
            dice[i] = random.Next(1, 7);

            switch (dice[i])
            { 
                case 1:
                    diceResults[0]++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    diceResults[1]++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    diceResults[2]++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    diceResults[3]++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    diceResults[4]++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    diceResults[5]++;
                    break;

            }

        }

        lbl_dice1.Image = diceImages[dice[0]];
        lbl_dice2.Image = diceImages[dice[1]];
        lbl_dice3.Image = diceImages[dice[2]];
        lbl_dice4.Image = diceImages[dice[3]];
        lbl_dice5.Image = diceImages[dice[4]];
    }

    private void GetResults()
    {
        bool oneRoll = false, fourRoll = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < diceResults.Length; i++)
        {
            if (diceResults[i] == 1 && diceResults[i] == 4)
            {
                oneRoll = true;
                fourRoll = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ResetResults()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry, what I need help with is being able to reset a dice image back to a blank dice if a player rolls a 1 or 4. However, allowing them to continue rolling their remaining dice, until they have no dice remaining.

Comment: @CodeCaster 
Eg. Roll 1 = 1, 3, 3, 4, 5. Player scores nothing, dice1 and dice4 are removed, leaving the player with 3 dice. 

Roll 2 = 5, 6, 3. Player scores 14 points and continues rolling until there are no dice left. Resulting in the other players turn.

Comment: I would make   diceResults  a list object.  This will work with your current code : diceResults = diceResults.Where(x => (x != 1) && (x != 4)).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng I'll give that a go. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has at least a couple of oddities that don't seem to fit with your description:

- The code simply *increments* an element in an array (`diceResults`) when a given die value is rolled (i.e. the element corresponds to the die *value*, not the die's order in the game). From your description, I would have expected the code to simply *add* the die value to a single sum variable.
- In your `GetResults()` method, your code compares the individual element values in the `diceResults` to the values `2` and `5`. In other words, for each possible die value, if that value comes up twice or five times, you set both flags. There are a number of reasons this is strange, but the biggest, most obvious one is that a single variable (i.e. the element `diceResults[i]`) can *never* have two different values at the same time. I.e. that array element will never be both `2` and `5`, as the `if` statement requires.

Given those issues, I'm more inclined to focus on the original specification than to trust the code too much in terms of trying to understand what your intended behavior of the code actually is. :)

It seems that the basic question is how best to remove die from play. The suggestion (in the comments above) to use a list to track the dice is certainly a workable one. In that approach, one would iterate through the list to set each element, and if the roll for a given element ever comes up as `1` or `4`, remove that element before moving on.

Having done that, one would just iterate through the list again to set the die value images, using the "blank" image for any die beyond the length of the list.

But there is a simpler way, and based on your statement *"setting that particular one back to blank"*, which seems to imply that each blank die should appear in the same position in which it was rolled, it seems like that simpler way might be preferable to you.

Specifically, after rolling the dice, just scan through the `dice` array and reset any `1` and `4` values to `0`, and use this `0` value as a special "sentinel" value to indicate that die is now blank.

Note that however you do this (with a list, or just setting values to `0`), there is also the question of whether to show the user the actual `1` and `4` rolls, or to immediately set those rolls to a blank die. I'm going to assume the former, but it would be very easy to implement it the other way instead. (As always, the beginning of good code is a good specification…right now, your specification is a bit light on detail, and thus is vague and ambiguous).

Taking that approach, your code might look something more like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    #region Declaration
    Image[] diceImages;
    Label[] labels;
    int[] dice;
    int diceTotal;
    bool checkOnesAndFours;
    Random random;
    #endregion

    #region Initialiazation;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initializing an array this way eliminates the chance of having
        // a typo in the array index for the assignment.
        diceImages = new Image[]
        {
            Properties.Resources.blank,
            Properties.Resources.one,
            Properties.Resources.two,
            Properties.Resources.three,
            Properties.Resources.four,
            Properties.Resources.five,
            Properties.Resources.six
        };

        // Arrays are always initialized with the elements having their default
        // values, so there's no need to specify `0` values for `int` arrays explicitly
        dice = new int[5];

        random = new Random();

        diceTotal = 0;

        // For the purposes of setting the dice images, it will be helpful
        // to keep the control references in an array. This is both convenient
        // and, again, helps guard against typographical errors
        labels = new Label[]
        {
            lbl_dice1,
            lbl_dice2,
            lbl_dice3,
            lbl_dice4,
            lbl_dice5
        };
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void btn_rollDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RollDice();
    }

    private void RollDice()
    {
        bool rolledOneOrFour = false;
        int rollTotal = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)
        {
            if (checkOnesAndFours)
            {
                // First, clear any 1 or 4 from the previous roll
                if (dice[i] == 1 || dice[i] == 4)
                {
                    dice[i] = 0;
                }

                // Then, ignore any blank die
                if (dice[i] == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            dice[i] = random.Next(1, 7);
            if (dice[i] == 1 || dice[i] == 4)
            {
                rolledOneOrFour = true;
            }
            rollTotal += dice[i];
        }

        if (!rolledOneOrFour)
        {
            diceTotal += rollTotal;
        }

        checkOnesAndFours = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
        {
            labels[i].Image = diceImages[dice[i]];
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

NOTE: it was not entirely clear to me what you mean to do when a `1` or `4` comes up. Taking what you wrote literally, I understand it to mean that if *any* die shows a `1` or `4` on a roll, that *none* of the dice count for that roll. The above code is implemented with that understanding in mind.

It occurs to me that you might have instead meant that only the dice that show `1` or `4` are not counted for the roll, and that the other dice for that roll are still included. It would not be hard to change the above to accommodate that alternative specification.

NOTE: you'll also notice that I have made other changes to the code not technically required in order to address the immediate question. I added comments in the code itself to try to explain why I made those changes, and why I feel they make the code better.

Just for grins, here's a version that does use a list instead:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    #region Declaration
    Image[] diceImages;
    Label[] labels;
    List<int> dice;
    int diceTotal;
    bool checkOnesAndFours;
    Random random;
    #endregion

    #region Initialiazation;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initializing an array this way eliminates the chance of having
        // a typo in the array index for the assignment.
        diceImages = new Image[]
        {
            Properties.Resources.blank,
            Properties.Resources.one,
            Properties.Resources.two,
            Properties.Resources.three,
            Properties.Resources.four,
            Properties.Resources.five,
            Properties.Resources.six
        };

        // Lists must be initialized explicitly with their initial values, as by default
        // they are initially empty.
        dice = new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5));

        random = new Random();

        diceTotal = 0;

        // For the purposes of setting the dice images, it will be helpful
        // to keep the control references in an array. This is both convenient
        // and, again, helps guard against typographical errors
        labels = new Label[]
        {
            lbl_dice1,
            lbl_dice2,
            lbl_dice3,
            lbl_dice4,
            lbl_dice5
        };
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void btn_rollDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RollDice();
    }

    private void RollDice()
    {
        bool rolledOneOrFour = false;
        int rollTotal = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dice.Count; i++)
        {
            // Clear any 1 or 4 from the previous roll
            if (checkOnesAndFours && (dice[i] == 1 || dice[i] == 4))
            {
                // Remove this die from play
                dice.RemoveAt(i);

                // The next list element to examine is now at the current i value
                // and the for loop is going to increment i when the continue
                // is executed, so decrement i in anticipation of that
                // so that the loop moves on to the correct next element
                i--;

                continue;
            }

            dice[i] = random.Next(1, 7);
            if (dice[i] == 1 || dice[i] == 4)
            {
                rolledOneOrFour = true;
            }
            rollTotal += dice[i];
        }

        if (!rolledOneOrFour)
        {
            diceTotal += rollTotal;
        }

        checkOnesAndFours = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
        {
            labels[i].Image = i < dice.Count ? diceImages[dice[i]] : diceImages[0];
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Finally, note that neither of the above addresses a couple of other issues with the code:

- Initializing the dice labels at the beginning of a game.
- Resetting the entire game once the game has ended (i.e. there are no more dice left).

I leave these two items as an exercise for the reader (of course, if you run into problems with those specific issues, you may always post another question on Stack Overflow asking about each specifically).

Comment: Thank you for your help and apologies if I wasn't clear with the question.

Regarding the two and 5, I was trying to think of numbers that would be common and thus penalize the player if that number was rolled. I found that 2 and 5 were very common so I used 1 and 4 instead (which I forgot to change in the code before asking the question). 

If a 1 or a 4 shows up then yes none of the dice count for that roll. I haven't come across using list instead and I appreciate having other different ways to implement this.

Comment: This part of code here:
    diceImages = new Image[]
        {
            Properties.Resources.blank;
            Properties.Resources.one;
            Properties.Resources.two;
            Properties.Resources.three;
            Properties.Resources.four;
            Properties.Resources.five;
            Properties.Resources.six;
        };

These should all have commas instead of the semi-colons yes?

Comment: _"so I used 1 and 4 instead"_ -- whether you use 2/5 or 1/4 is immaterial; the point is that the value you are checking is how many _times_ a particular die face appears, not _which_ die face appears. Note that when rolling a single 6-sided die, or when using the `Random.Next(1, 7)` method call, each number is _equally_ likely to occur. 2/5 is no more or less common or frequent than 1/4.

Comment: And yes, commas are needed rather than semicolons; one of the disadvantages of failing to provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is that answers often are just typed into a browser without even any compilation, never mind testing. :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I've followed through with your answer (array setup) Peter and now when I click the 'roll' button, nothing happens (dice images don't change) but there are no errors. I'm going through the `RollDice` method and I cannot see anything that would stop it from changing the dice images.

Comment: Without a good, complete code example, I can't really say what might be wrong. First, do make sure you aren't expecting the images to change as soon as the assignment in the `RollDice()` method happens. All that does is update the image reference. The program needs time to run after returning from the `Click` event handler to actually update the screen. Second, step through the debugger and make sure each statement does what you expect it to: `dice[i]` values should be updated, `diceImage[dice[i]]` references should correspond to the expected image resource references, etc.

Comment: FYI: I went ahead and wrote a complete, working example, based on the first code example I show above, and it works fine. So whatever problem you're running into, it's in code that is not included in _your_ code example.

Comment: Yeah I think my problem is a little more complex and it could be something wrong with my end. I have tried stepping through the debugger to check that the statements are doing what they should. When I try to add a watch to `RollDice()` in the watch dialogue box I get _The name 'RollDice' does not exist in the current context_.

I am going to write it again from scratch and I'll let you know how I go. Thank you

Comment: Well, for sure the code you posted had serious problems in it. So I hope that at least to the extent that I addressed those, you found the above helpful and in some way addressed your question (which I hope you intended to be more specific than just "fix my whole program for me"...that would obviously be too broad for Stack Overflow).

Comment: I am fairly new to this site and I was directed here by a colleague for help in coding. As I mentioned, I am learning to code so if I was very vague and unclear I apologize for that. After compiling the re-written solution, everything is running fine. I appreciate your time taken to help me Peter. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. No worries about the clarity of your question. It could stand a little improving, but I have seen far worse, and there was enough information there for a useful answer to be provided, which is of course the primary concern. Just as learning to code takes practice, so too does learning the best way to present a question. :) I am glad to hear that your program works well now. Have fun!